While calling one spring boot java service from another on linux server over HTTPS after 5 minutes getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Getting below exception after request takes more than 5 minutes -
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
I have tried increasing most of the timeouts at server, request, RestTemplate and HttpClient level but nothing worked like increasing and setting -

server.connection-timeout
RequestConfig requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(timeout).setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);
HttpClients.custom().setKeepAliveStrategy()
HttpClients.custom().evictIdleConnections()
RestTemplatebuilder.setReadTimeout(timeout).setConnectTimeout(timeout)

So, if you guys have any suggestion I will be grateful. Thanks!
